# how can fix stopped application when stop playing sound?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-mediaplayer

> I can stop sound from playing when lock the mobile but when it rotate
>   error application stopped unexpectedly occurred i used

```
  <activity
        android:name="x"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

> but when rotate the screen is white without any data. when i added this line of code

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

> it worked well but no rotate 
>   also another issue when i click back from mobile the same error occurred again

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    registerReceiver(listener, intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    super.onPause();
    wb.pause();
    unregisterReceiver(listener);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    wb.release();
    unregisterReceiver(listener);
}
```

Note : wb is instance for interface class WebAppInterface

```
 public void pause( ) {

      mp.pause();
}
public void release( ) {
      mp.stop();
  mp.release();
```

}

> 06-25 14:38:51.507: I/Process(295): Sending signal. PID: 295 SIG: 9
>   06-25 14:38:57.507: D/dalvikvm(311): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2068 objects / 194376 bytes in 145ms
>   06-25 14:38:59.376: W/KeyCharacterMap(311): No keyboard for id 0
>   06-25 14:38:59.376: W/KeyCharacterMap(311): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
>   06-25 14:38:59.546: D/AndroidRuntime(311): Shutting down VM
>   06-25 14:38:59.546: W/dalvikvm(311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.ramadan.Ramadan.onPause(Ramadan.java:125)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3842)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1190)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3335)
>   06-25 14:38:59.576: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  ... 12 more
>   06-25 14:39:20.727: I/Process(311): Sending signal. PID: 311 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

you need to have `mp.pasue()` in `onPause` and `mp.stop()` and `mp.release()` on `onDestroy`

Comment: I edited my code but the error " application stopped..." happened again when rotate and click back

Comment: `wb.release();` should be called only after `wb.stop()` this is because you cannot release when the file is in play

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to play the music in the service that way it won't be dependant on UI also you should release the mediaplayer in onDestroy method it's probably null you can check for it too

```
public void pause( ) {

if(mp!=null)
      mp.pause();
}
public void release( ) {

if(mp!=null)
  mp.release();
}
```

Comment: I edited my code but the error " application stopped..." happened  again when rotate and click back

Comment: try commenting your onConfigurationChanged Method and then testing it it may be because the new layout you are loading doen't contain the UI components you are using in your activity

Comment: in that case your listener must be null that's the last possibility

Comment: when i comment the ondestory method the error didn't happen but the sound doesn't stopped

Comment: that means your onconfig change is not woeking the activity is still recreating itself

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32341/discussion-between-egydeveloper-and-mera-client-chor-hai)